# Renaming groups in Rails group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an integer column which signifies a type of the model

If I do `Model.group(:type_model).count` for charting purposes I get a

```
{1 => 3
2 => 53
3 => 11}
```

Which by itself is fine, but it has no meaning. How can I replace the model type number with it's name (assuming I have a `name_of_type(int)` method)

I can map the hash and go over each key, but is there a better way to do this?